# Deno external package code throws error: window is undefined

Tags: typescript, npm, deno

I have imported an npm package to my Deno project. And in this package's code, there is a condition:

```
if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
  throw new Error('Error initializing the sdk: window is undefined');
}
```

Program throws "window is undefined" error at this condition above.

I am able to access window object in my Deno project. Also, when I add a breakpoint to condition line in the cache folder files, I can access to window object from debug console as well.

It would be great if someone help me resolve this problem to get my program working with the npm package that uses window object.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share how you're running deno and the script to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I am using `deno run --unstable --inspect-wait --allow-all ./main.ts` to run the program. 
Someone from the discord told me that npm packages get the node global object and "deno code" get's deno's global object. That's why window is not present. 
Any change do you know a workaround @MarcosCasagrande?

Comment: I moved the npm package's files into the Deno project and cleaned it up, resolving my problem.

Comment: I'd suggest you to bundle your solution and write your own answer to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NPM packages gets the Node global object. And the Deno code gets the Deno’s global object. That’s why window is not present in the NPM package’s code.

So, to be able to still use the desired 3rd party module. I forked the module and made it Deno compatible. Afterwards, imported it into Deno project.